# build missing Debian package dependency from source?

Tags: debian, apt, sparc

I'm currently trying to install PCP on Debian with sparc64. Unfortunately it requires the package `libreadline6 (>= 6.0)` which doesn't have an apt package for sparc64. libreadline7 does and is installed.

My solution was building gnu readline v6.3 from source (which worked), however I'm unsure how to proceed from here. Installing PCP via apt again lists the missing libreadline6 dependency. Is there another solution to this, other than building PCP completely from source as well?

Comment: I am sure that you can "hack" by using dpkg properties to make it understand that the package you built by source is already installed via source and commands like `dpkg-deb --build`... Have a look here if you think this method could help you: https://linuxconfig.org/easy-way-to-create-a-debian-package-and-local-package-repository ... I am not really an advanced linux user, so, feel free to ask me delete my comment. Just thought to share the idea but risked to be a stupid idea (even if I still feel it can be done with the inner method that dpkg is looking for the installed packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest option for you is to download `libreadline6` [from the Debian snapshots archive](https://snapshot.debian.org/package/readline6/6.3-9/#libreadline6_6.3-9); there’s a copy of the `sparc64` package there.

If you want to build it from source, I’d recommend building from [the `readline6` source package](https://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20161005T102332Z/pool/main/r/readline6/readline6_6.3-9.dsc). I can expand on that if necessary.

Comment: thanks that worked perfectly. however, what do you do, if theres no snapshot or port available? for example, the same package requires libpcp-pmda-perl, which requires perlapi-5.22.1, which again has no working package for sparc64 (altough according to https://packages.debian.org/sid/perl/libpcp-pmda-perl it should have, but isn't available for some reason)

Comment: Welcome to the world of non-release ports :-/. Any package pushed to Debian archives should be available from snapshots, but some ports never get built and the underlying issues won’t necessarily be fixed. `pcp` hasn’t been rebuilt since we moved away from Perl 5.22, so it still depends on `perlapi-5.22.1` which used to be provided by `perl-base` 5.22.1. Fixing that would involve rebuilding it with the current Perl. *That* hasn’t been done because `sparc64` doesn’t have some of the necessary dependencies (see [here](https://buildd.debian.org/status/package.php?p=libdbd-mysql-perl&suite=sid)).

Comment: So the only solution is finding a perl-base 5.22.1 snapshot or building perl-base 5.22.1 from source, and then building pcp from source?

Comment: No, you won’t be able to revert to Perl 5.22.1 easily. Rebuilding `pcp` from source (using the Debian source package) will pick up the current Perl and its dependencies. I suspect you’ll need to rebuild an older `pcp` than the current one (to avoid the MySQL/Galera dependencies).

Comment: I've tried both rebuilding pcp `3.10.9` from source (newest version without the need for libpcp-pmda-perl as far as im aware) as well as building a .deb with debuild from the snaphot of `3.10.8` and i run into the same issue, which I really cant make sense of: https://pastebin.com/AvYWb5m9

Comment: Ah, that’s a change between GCC 7 and 8; you need to either `#include <sys/sysmacros.h>` or (IIRC) build with `-std=c++11`.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks a lot!